# opera mini doesn't resize width when changing orientation 

Tags: javascript, css, opera, mobile-website, opera-mini

I am working on a mobile web project.The web app is working well in all mobile browser.But in opera mini it can not resize its width when the mobile phone is in landscape view. I have also tried different tags.Also tried with "viewport" meta name.But it doesn't work.
Can any one suggest any technique?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure you'll be able to do what you need in Opera Mini due to the way it serves pages via proxy servers and the limitations imposed on JavaScript functionality: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opera_Mini#Functionality

Answer (score 1):

Opera Mini is a thin client which receives an "intelligent" image (OBML) precompiled on Opera Servers. When you enter an address, the thin client on your phone sends it to Opera servers which does the real HTTP request to the distant server. Then the Opera servers receive the response, create the image and sends it back to the thin client. So per se there is no css, html, js reaching the thin client. Just the OBML image. So when you change the orientation of the device you need to make a reload of the page to be effective. This is the trade-off in between saving bandwidth (80%) and live interactions on the device.

Do not hesitate to ask more questions.